# Web Scraper does work on one site but not on another

Tags: python, web-scraping, visual-studio-code, screen-scraping

so i have this really basic scraper just to get the Infro from the View Source:

import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

r = requests.get("https:nytimes.com")

print(r.text)

And to test it i used the nytimes and it worked. However i want to **scrape** the View source of the sneaker site named Goat.com but whenever i change the link and save it and run it i get in VSC just the path where i saved the file with the message (running) and when i try to run it in the terminal with "python 3 (filename)" and hit enter ,then it just jumps to the row below and bugs out to a point where the terminal doesnt recognize other stuff and hitting enter just makes it go down to the next row and so on.

BTW i am really new to this so im sorry if i forgot something important to mention

Comment: Your question is not clear

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check whether URL is correct
I can see the url you have entered has some mistake. Try https://www.nytimes.com/

Comment: ty turned out the link was wrong as you said+ it jjust takes a few minutes to load it up

Comment: The problem solved?